# What is an idiomatic translation of "practice makes perfect"?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

In English, we say "practice makes perfect" to indicate that practice of a skill leads to mastery.  So a Latin teacher might attempt to inspire a student to diligence by saying "Write out these declensions 50 times.  Practice makes perfect."

What is an idiomatic way of saying this phrase in Latin, preferably Classical Latin?  I notice that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(U)) lists a phrase,  *usus est magister optimus*, to mean this, but [a search for that phrase in the Classical corpus](http://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=usus+est+magister+optimus) comes back with nothing.  Is this the best option available?

Comment: One option would be *repetitio est mater studiorum*. This appears to be postclassical, and is of unknown origin according to my dictionary. Let's hope someone finds a suitable phrase in the classical literature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised to find that apparently *usus facit magistrum* isn't attested until the XIX century. However:

> **Usus est magister optimus**,

was actually first written by [Cicero](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0013:text=Rab.%20Post.:chapter=4&highlight=usus%2Cmagister%2Coptimus) (Rab. Post. 4). Note that [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22usus%20est%20magister%20optimus%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=todVV4aEC9ilxgTw3omwCA) the sentence with quotes gives 65K+ results.

Variants include alternative word orders and later statements such as *usus facit habitum*, *usus facit artem* and even a couple of *exercitatio facit habitum*.

A less direct phrase, although arguably more *idiomatic* may be:

> **Gutta cavat lapidem** non vi sed saepe cadendo,

the first part being written by Ovid [(Pont. 4.10)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2008.01.0493:book=4:poem=10&highlight=lapidem%2Ccavat%2Cgutta), and the second one added in medieval times ([according to WP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqpYy5ypPNAhXF2T4KHXLgA2oQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FList_of_Latin_phrases_(G)&usg=AFQjCNGRni9I3RjPQmfMaPc7vu-6F4uMSg&sig2=3HREKvF4y-CpUZBe8spSdA)) and recorded by [Giordano Bruno](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutta_cavat_lapidem) in *The Torchbearer*.

Actually my Latin professor used *gutta cavat lapidem...* to encourage us to study.

Answer (score 1):

There's a phrase used by the pharmacist Homais in Gustav Flaubert's 'Madame Bovary':

> "Fabricando fit faber, age quod agis"

Which translates as "Practice makes perfect" or, more literally, "It is by making that you become a maker, whatever it is that you do."

I can't speak for how historically accurate it may be / how good Flaubert's Latin was.

Answer (score 0):

Another Ciceronian option, which I just stumbled across and which reminded me of this question, is from *De Oratore*, "Demosthenes perfecit meditando ut nemo planius locutus esse putaretur" (Demosthenes by practicing achieved the result that no was thought to have spoken more clearly). Perhaps *Meditando perficitur* would suit. The two words *perfecit meditando* are almost a calque of the English phrase, and yet are attested classically.

Not classically attested, but an old saw which means almost exactly what I mean when I say "Practice makes perfect" is *Repetita juvant*, doing things again and again helps.